# how can I iterate the elements of an array and show a message when it's in the middle in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I am a newbie trying to understand the basics of Javascript with some basic exercises but I can't do this one. Any idea of how should I write it instead?

```
var array5 = [1,2,3,4,5];

for (var i=0; i<array5.length; i++) {
console.log(array5[i]);
  if (array5===[2]) {
  alert("we are in the middle of loop");}
}
```

PD: by the way, it has to be using the for loop and conditional if.

Thanks!

Comment: `if (i == Math.floor(array5.length/2)) {`

Comment: You're using `=` inside an if, you want a comparison `===` not an assignment

Comment: While this is certainly a duplicate, I don't see how this question duplicates the one chosen. If anything, it would just confuse a beginner.

Comment: Sterling Archer, I still don't get the output when writing it as you said:var array5 = [1,2,3,4,5];

for (var i=0; i<array5.length; i++) {
console.log(array5[i]);
  if (array5===[2]) {
  alert("we are in the middle of loop");}
}

Comment: @Sterling Archer I don't see neither this is a duplicate of the one you proposed really... could you please answer it instead referring it to another issue. As I said it still doesn't work with the === you said before. Thanks